# MRJ-21 Patch Panel System

Tags: datacenter, cable, networking

I was reading about the MRJ-41 Patch Panel system [here](http://www.ampnetconnect.com/system_group_overview.asp?sys_id=80), but not sure I entirely understand it.  It looks like it allows me to wire my own patch panels because it it uses a special cable to attach the patch panels together (so I don't need an electrician).

However, it looks like each 48 port panel requires 8 of these cables.  So to connect a rack to another rack, I would need 2 patch panels ([CDW](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?edc=1105866&cm_mmc=ShoppingFeeds-_-GoogleBase-_-Cables-_-1105866_AMP%20NETCONNECT%20MRJ%2021%20-%20patch%20panel%20-%201U_AMP-1435971-1#PO) $330 each) and then 8 cables ([CDW](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1843404) $240) , for a total of about $2500 per patch.

Am I understanding the purpose and implementation correctly?

Comment: This is a tidier way to connect patch panels together, but you pay a bundle for their cables and panels.  How far apart are the racks?  It looks like they come up to 80m, but I don't think you'd be able to pull them through the walls - too thick.

Comment: Ward: All next to each other in 100sq ft cage, so not far

Comment: I'm curious: what do you want this for?  I can see using it in a huge datacenter, or in a smaller one if you use their patch panel with an octopus cable to "move" switch ports from one location in the rack to another.

Comment: A Octopus cable? This just for wiring main rack to the other 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my name is Jeff O'Rand and I work for Tyco Electronics ( Amp ) and can answer any of your questions concerning the MR21 product offering.

Main benefits:

Reduced cable bundle OD = better airflow

6 to 10 times quicker to install = less labor dollars to install

Reusable = if your cage or racks change, the cables can be reused

Pricing is somewhat higher than buying 4pr and jacks and panels............but much less expensive when you consider the labor savings.

We are set to release an even smaller OD cable assembly to support 2 thru 20 meter applications